# How to configure Restlet for Google AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

I am trying to create a restful web service using restlet running on Google AppEngine using Eclipse as the java editor.  Some hours of googling, reading message, etc. and I'm nowhere further forward in configuring this.  The articles have to be there but finding them is hard.

Would anyone have a simple (exactly what to do, what files to copy, etc.) tutorial for setting this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well you can go through this tutorial [Reslet With GAE](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.2/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html).

Here is also one more example [Another Example](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.2/13-restlet/275-restlet/252-restlet.html).

Its very simple thing, just put the necessary jars on the build path ie under **WEB-INF/lib**, and start your application.

Comment: Due to a temporary hardware failure, you can follow this link if the one above doesn't autoredirect you: http://web.archive.org/web/http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.2/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, Google's own implementation of REST is called App Engine Endpoints: http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/
It's still in beta, but it's easy to get access.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently on the same situation as you are. All I can say is that there's a lot to work on to successfully implement Restlet on AppEngine. What you need to do is

1. Download the most stable version of **[Restlet for Google App Engine](http://restlet.org/download/current#release=stable&edition=gae&distribution=zip)**.
2. Extract the compressed file into an easy-to-remember location
3. Navigate to the Restlet libraries directory. For example, if the extraction location is `/opt/restlet` then go to `/opt/restlet/restlet-gae-`*`[version]`*`/lib`
4. You should be able to find there the java packages **`org.restlet.jar`** and **`org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar`**.
5. Copy those two packages and paste it into your *`[gae-project]`*`/war/WEB-INF/lib`
6. Using your Eclipse, refresh the `lib` directory of your GAE project
7. **Select** the newly added jar packages > **Right Click** > **Build Path** > **Add to Build Path**

Then after that all you need to do is to follow the **[Restlet Edition for Google App Engine Tutorial](http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.2/editions/gae)**.

It should do the trick.

Edit:
Due to this question, I created a [Tutorial for Integrating Restlet to App Engine](http://abelcallejo.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/restlet-hello-world-tutorial-for-google-app-engine/).